# Save list condition on data refresh AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got a list of items, each item is expandable one. I'm using uib-collapse for this. Each time I receive data, I add isCollapsed property to each object in array. Then I bind them to UI list using ng-repeat. But I need to refresh data each minute. And here comes the problem : all expanded items are closed due to array was updated. I need to save list state and expanded items on data refresh. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you updating the complete array. Can you explain more or create a fiddle?

Comment: @SrujanReddy yes. Each minute I update the entire array. And again add isCollapsed field to each item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use $localStorage

assign your data to `$localstorage` param and set back data once the page is refreshed,

```
.controller("MyCtrl",function($scope,$localStorage){

    if($localStorage.list != null)
        $scope.list = $localStorage.list;

    $scope.add = function(obj){
        $scope.list.push(obj);
        $localStorage.list = $scope.list;
    }

});
```

If you refresh the page `$scope.list` will get the value from the `$localstorage`.

Comment: I'm not refreshing the page. I just refresh the list in page,other parts of the page stay as they were

Answer (score 0):

just use map of boolean flags pointing to your list items, and use these flags as your *uib-collapse* value.

JS:

```
$scope.reload = function () {
  $http.get('list.json').then(function (data) {
    $scope.list = data && data.data || [];
  });
};

$scope.collapsedFlags = {};

$scope.reload();
```

HTML:

```
<div class="well well-lg" ng-repeat="item in list track by item.id">
  <button class="btn btn-default" 
          ng-click="collapsedFlags[item.id] = !collapsedFlags[item.id]">
    {{ item.isCollapsed ? '+' : '-' }}
  </button>
  <div uib-collapse="collapsedFlags[item.id]" ng-bind="item.value"></div>
</div>
```

PLUNKER: https://plnkr.co/edit/87vVb8Jjyz6yFGAjiHBK?p=preview